# Probability density function - 95% probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

A factory has as a by product a liquid that needs to be stored in a tank. The weekly volume of liquid is presented by the following probability density function:

$$f(x) = 105x^4(1-x)^2 \ \ \mbox{for} \  0 \leq x \leq 1.$$

The storage tank is to be emptied once a week. How big does the storage tank need to be so there is 95% probability of it not flowing over?

I have tried to integrate the function, resulting in the cdf, setting that equal to .95 and solving for x. Is x the size of the tank? What values would result in an overflow?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: As you are new to the site:  people here tend to not respond well, or at all, to questions like this that look like homework problems and which show no effort.  What have you tried?  Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: You're on the right track. $F(x)=0.95$ means probability of volume not exceeding $x$ (not overflowing) is 0.95. Solve for $x$ and that's your answer.

Comment: As a hint:  I'd just solve for $x$ numerically.  That is, I wouldn't even try to look for an algebraic solution.

Comment: So I got x = 0.871244, does this make any sense?

Comment: Just similar to the above comments - Let $X$ be the weekly volume of the liquid and $c$ be the capacity of the storage tank to be determined. It is not flowing over if and only if $X \leq c$, therefore you want to solve for  $c$ by setting $\Pr\{X \leq c\} = 0.95 = F_X(c)$. So from here you express the CDF in terms of the pdf.

Comment: The numerical answer agrees with mine.